# EXCEL 2010 VB code xml data format

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a complex spreadsheet that I need to get into xml data format.  I've used Excel 2010 to create the complex spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet itself has multiple tabs, and a table with a lot of formulas.  The spreadsheet also contains some VB code for hiding a tab unless it is a specific user.  I need this in XML data format, along with the VB code intact.  If I save it as XML Spreadsheet 2003 format, it gives the correct formatting, however the VB code is lost during the saving of the spreadsheet.  Is there an option out there to save this file in XML Spreadsheet 2003 format that will keep the VB code?

Comment: I guess that you can't use 2 files: one in xml format and the other one in xlsm (that format will include your macros)

Comment: Unfortunately it must be one file.  The file format must be text and not encrypted as I will be writting a program in another language to produce the xml.

Comment: Well xlsm is a format that stores the macro and according to MSDN[1] it is XML based `The Office Excel 2007 XML-based and macro-enabled file format`. So you might be able to parse that xlsm file directly.


  [1]: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx

Comment: Is there a way do decrypt the file after saving it in The Office Excel 2007 XML-based and macro-enabled file format?  I need to copy the XML code and manipulate it, then I need to be able to re-open the spreadsheet using the XML code in excel.  XML Spreadsheet 2003 would work, but I'm missing the VB code to hide a spreadsheet tab. Is there an excel element for XML spreadsheet 2003 for VB code?  Maybe I could manually add it....

Comment: I would recommand that you manipulate your excel file without xml (if possible), instead use existing tools. Take a look http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084/en. Other than that I can't help you, maybe someone else will have the answer